# how to cast certain key values to floats using python

Tags: python, dictionary, casting

Given this dictionary:

```
my_dict={'animal':['Dog','Cat'],'age':[4,5],'bark':[True,False],'badge_num':['234','896']}
```

what code will cast 'age' to float?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Python is dynamically typed. You can treat pretty much anything as a float (where it makes sense). That being said, float(n) turns n into a float if desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `map` combined with `float` like the following:

```
my_dict['age']=list(map(float, my_dict['age']))
```